# Animating transition from one list to another

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js to manage lists of items (see [this page for demo](http://www.ugile.com/sim)).

Items transition from one list to another, and I'd like to animate this transition.

I know I can animate transitioning in and out separately, but I actually want to see the items fly from their location in the original list to their location in the destination list.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EpRDY/3/

The problem is that I have access to the afterAdd and beforeRemove separately, but not to the combination of both.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite tricky. I have a solution but it's a little messy. Maybe you can find a cleaner way.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/Twu4L/

Hope this helps.